# React forEach not being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

If I console.log `item.name` just before the `<h1>` tags I do see all the item names in the console, however, for some reason they are not getting printed in the `<h1>` or any other tags.

```
import React from 'react'

function Product(props) {
  const newArr = props.list.map((product) => {
      return {name: product.name, price: product.price, description: product.description}
  })
  return(
      <div>
        {newArr.forEach((item) => {
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
        })}
      </div>
  )  
}

export default Product
```

Please help

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything; ever. Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()` instead, and specify a **unique key attribute** to the returning element. In this case, i assume it's `name`, i recommend using an unique `id` or something like that.

```
<div>
    {newArr.map((item) => 
        <h1 key={item.name}>{item.name}</h1>
     })
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `map()`. It is the best way to render data in React JS
[something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8YQq.png)

source: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html